# Can I change the current network interface in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, networking, cmd, interface

In my current setup I have two interfaces, one is my normal connection and the other for my VPN, which is the default interface.

My VPN isn't nearly as fast as my connection so for some heavier load I use my normal connection. The problem I am having is that I want to send files to Google Drive by using their api via CMD, but googleapis.com simply resolves to too many IP's to route them all. Currently I am solving this issue by connecting through a proxy so I only have to route that proxy to my normal interface.

What I would rather do is just set the interface of my normal connection to the CMD session like I do with the proxy. I have tried playing around with netsh but so far with no success.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Ask your question on https://superuser.com. This is a programming site.

Comment: If you do not get resolution from http://superuser.com, you might try https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It isn;t that your VPN is your "Default Interface" it's that it has a Lower Route Metric for Traffic because whoever set it up made it so that all traffic routes t the VPN instead of only internal traffic.

If this is intentional, and you don;t want to change it then your only real option is to use a Proxy as you need to be able to sniff the packet headers to match the API URL, and it's it's HTTPS traffic, that is encrypted, and only passing through a proxy will be able to get around that.